# Remove chars in a string Django python

Tags: django, templates

When I post a value from my page an extra string is create and I would like to remove the 'pattern = "' is there a tag i could use or replace function i can use to remove pattern =" and the ending ". Please find below scenario:

`pattern = "apple"`

Desired output

`apple`

I tried using but to no success.Is there another method i could use newbie at django python.

`{{ pattern|split  }}`

Comment: if You know that is the pattern, can you not parse it in the view and send it to the template in the context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) (a capture group would do the trick) to replace the desired part.

Answer (score 0):

If the quotation marks are added to your string when you are submitting the form, you could use the .strip() method when accessing the POST data. You can also specify what characters you want to remove. Check it out here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html